# Using multiple WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with different AuthenticationProviders (basic auth for API and LDAP for web app)

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, basic-authentication

According the [Spring Security Reference section 5.7](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html) it should be possible to define more than one security adapter.

I try to do the same but without success. After a server reboot, the first x times the API works fine with basic auth, but after a couple of times I'm redirected to the login (form) page, this should only happen for our web app, not for the API calls.

My code:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig  {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private Environment env;

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().
                withUser("admin").password("pw_test").roles(API_ROLE);
        }

        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
              .antMatcher("/services/**")
              .authorizeRequests()
              .anyRequest().hasRole(API_ROLE)
              .and()
              .httpBasic()
              .and()
              .csrf()
              .disable();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private Environment env;

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
            auth.eraseCredentials(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // LDAP FORM AUTHENTICATION
            http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login.html").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll() 
                .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll() 
                .antMatchers("/images/**").permitAll() 
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().formLogin()
                .failureUrl("/login.html?error=1")
                .loginPage("/login.html")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/success.html")
                .usernameParameter("j_username")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
                .permitAll();

            http.csrf().disable();

            // iFRAMES SETTINGS
            http
                .headers()
                .frameOptions().sameOrigin()
                .httpStrictTransportSecurity().disable();

            // HTTPS
            http
                .requiresChannel()
                .anyRequest()
                .requiresSecure();

            //MAP 8080 to HTTPS PORT
            http.portMapper().http(8080).mapsTo(443);
        }

        @Bean
        public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
            CustomLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new CustomLdapAuthenticationProvider(env.getProperty("ldap.domain"), env.getProperty("ldap.url"), env.getProperty("ldap.base"));
            provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
            provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
            return provider;
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea?

I'm using Spring Boot version 1.4.1-RELEASE and Spring Security version 4.1.3-RELEASE.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You use the same [`AuthenticationManager`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationManager.html) for both configurations, because you autowire the same [`AuthenticationManagerBuilder`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/builders/AuthenticationManagerBuilder.html).

See [Spring Security Architecture](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture/):

> ```
> @Configuration
> public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
>
>     ... // web stuff here
>
>     @Autowired
>     public void initialize(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder, DataSource dataSource) {
>         builder.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).withUser("dave")
>             .password("secret").roles("USER");
>     }
>
> }
> ```
>
> This example relates to a web application, but the usage of `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` is more widely applicable (see below for more detail on how web application security is implemented). Note that the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` is `@Autowired` into a method in a `@Bean` - that is what makes it build the global (parent) AuthenticationManager. In contrast if we had done it this way:
>
> ```
> @Configuration
> public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
>
>     @Autowired
>     DataSource dataSource;
>
>     ... // web stuff here
>
>     @Override
>     public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) {
>         builder.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).withUser("dave")
>             .password("secret").roles("USER");
>     }
>
> }
> ```
>
> (using an `@Override` of a method in the configurer) then the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` is only used to build a "local" `AuthenticationManager`, which is a child of the global one.