# Spring Security - multiple configurations - add LogoutHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, security, spring-security

I have a spring-boot application using spring-security. The security configuration is split into multiple instances of [`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutHandler.html).

I have one where I configure logout in general:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    // configure logout
    http
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .addLogoutHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
                System.out.println("logged out 1!");
            })
            .permitAll();

    // ... more security configuration, e.g. login, CSRF, rememberme
}
```

And there is another [`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutHandler.html), where I want to do almost nothing, except adding another LogoutHandler:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    // configure logout
    http
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .addLogoutHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
                System.out.println("logged out 2!");
            });
}
```

Both `configure()` methods are called. However, if I do log out, only the first [`LogoutHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutHandler.html) is called. Changing the `@Order` of both configurations does not change the result.

What is missing in my configuration?

Comment: Are you trying to register two logout handlers to the same url or are you trying to specifically have a logout that does not run everything else?

Comment: Both LogoutHandlers should run on the same logout.

Comment: Try that link, https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity I think your url are same so.

Comment: I know that link of course, but at what part should I look especially? My point is to modularize the configuration feature-wise.

Comment: They have @Order(2) and @Order(3), and changing it does NOT affect which handler is called. It's always the one in the more "wide" configuration. Anyway, I would in both cases expect that both are called. But maybe that's not possible with the current version?

Answer (score 10):

When you create several security configurations Spring Boot will create a separate SecurityFilterChain for each of them. See [WebSecurity](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/WebSecurity.java#L290):

```
@Override
protected Filter performBuild() throws Exception {
    // ...
    for (SecurityBuilder<? extends SecurityFilterChain> securityFilterChainBuilder : securityFilterChainBuilders) {
        securityFilterChains.add(securityFilterChainBuilder.build());
    }
    // ...
}
```

When application gets logout request [FilterChainProxy](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/FilterChainProxy.java#L226) will return only one SecurityFilterChain:

```
private List<Filter> getFilters(HttpServletRequest request) {
    for (SecurityFilterChain chain : filterChains) {
        // Only the first chain that matches logout request will be used:
        if (chain.matches(request)) {
            return chain.getFilters();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

If you really need modular security configuration I would suggest to create a separate security configuration for logout and other realms. You can define logout handlers as beans (using `@Bean` annotation) in different configuration classes and collect these handlers in logout configuration:

**WebSecurityLogoutConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@Order(99)
public class WebSecurityLogoutConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // ALL YOUR LOGOUT HANDLERS WILL BE IN THIS LIST
    @Autowired
    private List<LogoutHandler> logoutHandlers;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // configure only logout
        http
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                // USE CompositeLogoutHandler
                .addLogoutHandler(new CompositeLogoutHandler(logoutHandlers));
        http.csrf().disable(); // for demo purposes
    }
}
```

**WebSecurity1Configuration.java**

```
@Configuration
@Order(101)
public class WebSecurity1Configuration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // ... more security configuration, e.g. login, CSRF, rememberme
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/secured/**")
                .authenticated();
    }

    // LOGOUT HANDLER 1
    @Bean
    public LogoutHandler logoutHandler1() {
        return (request, response, authentication) -> {
            System.out.println("logged out 1!");
        };
    }
}
```

**WebSecurity2Configuration.java**

```
@Configuration
@Order(102)
public class WebSecurity2Configuration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**")
                .permitAll();
    }

    // LOGOUT HANDLER 2
    @Bean
    public LogoutHandler logoutHandler2() {
        return (request, response, authentication) -> {
            System.out.println("logged out 2!");
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: When I have all `LogoutHandler`s in a single place, do I still need the `CompositeLogoutHandler` or couldn't I just add all of them in a loop? Other than that, your answer looks very promising.

Answer (score 0):

You should be solving this problem with the [CompositeLogoutHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/CompositeLogoutHandler.html) on your single `/logout` operation endpoint.

You can still keep two [WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html)'s as desired, but you'll be conglomerating the logout functionality for two `LogoutHandler`s into a single composite action:

```
new CompositeLogoutHandler(loggedOutHandler1, loggedOutHandler2);
```

Comment: That is the kind of manual wiring I would like to avoid (not much magic happening inside `CompositeLogoutHandler`). I want to provide an independent `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, which will add functionality working by itself. Simplest example would be logging each login and logout. But it seems like `addLogoutHandler` is behaving more like a `setLogoutHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

The keypoint is you should create separated instance of AuthenticationManger.

[Here is an sample for multiples WebSecurityAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40258583/using-multiple-websecurityconfigureradapter-with-different-authenticationprovide)