# Spring security antMatcher does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

**EDIT:**

I further drilled down the problem and turns out issue persists even with single configuration. If I use single configuration and keep

```
http.antMatcher("/api/test/**")
```

urls don't get secured. 
Removing the antMatcher and antMatchers immediately secures the url. 
i.e if I use:

```
http.httpBasic()
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest()
    .authenticated();
```

then only spring security is securing url. Why isn't antMatcher functioning?

(Updated the title to include actual issue.)

---

**Original Post:**

I have referred following stackoverflow questions:

1. [Spring REST security - Secure different URLs differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33037559/spring-rest-security-secure-different-urls-differently)
2. [Using multiple WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with different AuthenticationProviders (basic auth for API and LDAP for web app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40258583/using-multiple-websecurityconfigureradapter-with-different-authenticationprovide)

and spring security doc:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity

But I am not able to configure multiple http security elements.
When I follow the official spring doc, it works in my case only becuase of the fact that the second http security element is a catch-all, but as soon as I add a specific url, all the urls can be accessed without any authentication.

Here's my code:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean                                                             
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() throws Exception {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        manager.createUser(User.withUsername("user").password("userPass").roles("USER").build());
        manager.createUser(User.withUsername("admin").password("adminPass").roles("ADMIN").build());
        return manager;
    }


    @Configuration
    @Order(1)                                                        
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override       
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) 
          throws Exception {            
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER");
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
        }

        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/api/v1/**")                               
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").authenticated()
                    .and()
                .httpBasic();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override       
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) 
          throws Exception {

            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user1").password("user").roles("USER");
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin1").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/api/test/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/test/**").authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin();
        }
    }
}
```

Now any url can be accessed. If I remove antMatcher from second configuration, all the urls become secured.

Comment: The same url becomes secured and non-secured just by removing/adding the antMatcher. For e.g. if I access localhost:8100/api/test/hello, I get prompted for username password only if there is no antMatcher line.

Comment: api is my context root. I had tried starstartest/starstar but it doesn&amp;#39;t work either (used wildchar * word star. Stackoverflow Android  app is converting wildchar to bold formatting. Used double star before and after test/)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The pattern must not contain the context path, see [`AntPathRequestMatcher`](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/AntPathRequestMatcher.html):

> Matcher which compares a pre-defined ant-style pattern against the URL ( `servletPath` + `pathInfo`) of an `HttpServletRequest`.

and [`HttpServletRequest.html#getServletPath`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getServletPath--):

> Returns the part of this request's URL that calls the servlet. This path starts with a "/" character and includes either the servlet name or a path to the servlet, but does not include any extra path information or a query string. Same as the value of the CGI variable SCRIPT_NAME.

and [`HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath--):

> Returns the portion of the request URI that indicates the context of the request. The context path always comes first in a request URI. The path starts with a "/" character but does not end with a "/" character. For servlets in the default (root) context, this method returns "". The container does not decode this string.

Your modified and simplified code:

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .antMatcher("/test/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

#application.properties

server.servlet.context-path=/auth-api

add only resource patch (Controller path) in antMatchers("/v1/authenticate")
should it antMatchers("/auth-api/v1/authenticate")

##WebSecurityConfig###
httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/v1/authenticate","/hello")
.permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().exceptionHandling()
.authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);