# AntMatcher and contextPath for API security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I have spring boot application. I have configured `OAuth2` - both authorization and resource servers (separated). In the resource server (`application.properties`) I have:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/api
```

as well as:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    (...)

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http
                .requestMatchers()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**", "/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**" ).authenticated();
    }
}
```

The problem is that, api is not actually secured at all. Thanks to doc and [@dur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48295894/spring-security-antmatcher-does-not-work?rq=1) I know that

> The pattern must not contain the context path

Indeed, changing from:

```
.antMatchers("/api/**" ).authenticated();
```

to:

```
.antMatchers("/**" ).authenticated();
```

works fine. But the question is: is it possible to use context-path in this use case, instead of using `/**` ? I could repeat `.antMatchers()` for each and every controller (or use `/**`) but maybe there is a way to use context-path ?

Comment: `2.0.5.RELEASE`

Comment: Why do you need the context path? Why do you think that it is better? However, you could always implement your own `RequestMatcher`.

Comment: I think it's more readable when you use specific context `/api/**` more than everything `/**`. It gives me sense that I didn't accidentally influence something beyond `/api/**`. Second reason might be a situation where I have multiple contexts and want to apply different security logic to each.

Answer (score 0):

1. Inject the property into variable and use that in code
2. I am also demonstrating IMHO nicer way of writing the conf with lambda where you do not need to use ".and()" and you can see scope blocks better.
3. Empty `.requestMatchers().and()` does nothing, so you can remove it.
   which would also be more obvious in lambda notation :
   `.requestMatchers(matchers -> matchers)`

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    (...)
    @Value("${server.servlet.context-path:''}")
    private String contextPath; // <<<< I am the path !

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize 
                .antMatchers(contextPath + "/actuator/**", "/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(contextPath + "/**" ).authenticated()
            );
    }
}
```

But if you really want to, you can also write the code the old way too.
It has no effect on using the variable.
:

```
 http. 
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(contextPath + "/actuator/**", "/api-docs/**")
    .permitAll()
    .antMatchers(contextPath + "/**" )
    .authenticated()
    .and());
```